# Android Google Maps, multiple intents

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have some google maps markers (10) with info window. By clicking on an info window a new activity should start and a value should be transfered via intent.put extra():
My problem is that always the value of the last marker is transfered to the next activity, although i click on another info window, in this case it's 101010.
My Code:

```
 Marker marker1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(itemList.get(1))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getDrawableId(imagename)))
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(itemList.get(2)), Double.parseDouble(itemList.get(3))))

            );



            System.out.println("MoID=" + monsterid1);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker1) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(showmap.this, MonsterDetail.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("monsterid", monsterid); //value i want to transfer to next activity e.g "111"
                    startActivity(intent1);


                }
            });


Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(itemList.get(5))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getDrawableId(imagename)))
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(itemList.get(6)), Double.parseDouble(itemList.get(7))))

            );



            System.out.println("MoID=" + monsterid1);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker2) {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(showmap.this, MonsterDetail.class);
                    intent2.putExtra("monsterid", monsterid2); //value i want to transfer to next activity e.g. "222"
                    startActivity(intent2);


                }
            });

Marker marker10 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
...
...
...
 intent10.putExtra("monsterid", monsterid10); //value i want to transfer to next activity e.g. "101010"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnInfoWindowClickListener` is for the *map*, not the *marker*. So, your current code is:

- Creating an `OnInfoWindowClickListener`
- Creating another `OnInfoWindowClickListener`, throwing away the previous one
- and so on

Call `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` **once**. In `onInfoWindowClick()`, you are passed a `Marker` that represents what the user clicked on. Using that `Marker`, determine the value of the extra to put into your `Intent`. For example, IIRC, `Marker` has a `getId()` method, so you could have a `HashMap<String, String>` mapping marker IDs to extra values, where in `onInfoWindowClick()` you look up the value for the clicked-upon marker.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem fixed :)